# Is there a search engine that searches for the exact words you enter, exactly how you entered them?

Tags: search-engine, case-sensitive, punctuation

Is there a search engine that has some of the following features?

Case *sensitive*: "LaTeX" != "latex"

*Doesn't* mess with punctuation in a quoted phrase: "Yes!!!" != "Yes?"

*Doesn't* search for words that have the same stem: "fracture" != "fractured"

Comment: Google seems to behave not as I expected.  It worked as of four months ago... something changed.

Comment: Wow that is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

i came across this so-called [Case sensitive Google search](http://case-sensitive-search.appspot.com/) .. it's merely okay .. the examples i tried were hit-n-miss on its actual utility

Comment: The site is down.

Answer (score 0):

Seems no..

And if there is, I don't think it can give enough results...

Comment: Limiting the number of results is exactly the point, though. When looking for a needle, one doesn't need an ever-larger haystack.